# How to Add Time Input to Sheets Depending on User Dropdown Selection

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm wondering how can I achieve the following by modifying my existing code.

- Add the time input into Time Activated Column (Column B) when Activate dropdown is selected
- Add the time input when user selected Deactivate, it should be added under column C
- An error message when column C is Blank and user added new activate entry
- Add time duration in the HTML form when active

HTML Dropdown is Activate and Deactivate.

Here's my Sheet and form looks like.

[image]
[image]

GS

```
function saveData(obj) {
  
    let sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Feedback');
    let dateString = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    //Saving records to Google Sheet
    sheet.appendRow([
      obj.data1,
      obj.data2,
      dateString,
      Session.getActiveUser().getUsername()
      ]);

return true;
}
```

JS

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click',submitForm);


function submitForm(){
  let input1 = document.getElementById('input1');
  let input2 = document.getElementById('input2');

  let obj = {
    data1 : input1.value,
    data2 : input2.value

  };
  if(input1.value  == "" || input2.value ==""){
  Swal.fire({
  icon: 'info',
  title: 'Oops. Please fill out the blank fields!'
  
})
}
 else{

Swal.fire({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
  icon: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  showDenyButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, enact this!',
  denyButtonText: 'No, revert this!'
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.isConfirmed) {
     google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler( () => {
      input1.value = "";
      input2.value = "";
       } )
       .saveData(obj);
        $("#input2").val('');
        $("#input1").prop("selectedIndex", 0);
      

    Swal.fire({
  icon: 'success',
//  width: 600,
  title: 'Message!',
  text: 'Draft communication has been sent to your personal email!',
  confirmButtonText:
    '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Awesome!',
  confirmButtonAriaLabel: 'Thumbs up, great!',
})
  }
  else if (result.isDenied) {
    Swal.fire('Changes are not saved', '', 'info')
    input1.value = "";
    input2.value = "";
  }
})

};

  };
</script>
```

HTML

```
   <div class="header">
  <h1>Activation tool</h1>
  <p>.</p>
</div>


        <div class="frame">
          <h3 class-="mb-4">Enactment Tool</h3>

          <label for="need" class="form-label">Enactment Request: *</label>
          <div class="mb-4">
            <select id="input1" class="form-control">
                          <option value="" selected disabled>--Select Your Request--</option>
                          <option>Activate</option>
                          <option>Deactivate</option>
                    </select>
          </div>
          <label for="time" class="form-label">Time: *</label>
          <div class="mb-4">
            <input id="input2" class="form-control" type="datetime-local" name="time">
          </div>
          <div>
            <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Send Email </button>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `An error message when user selected activate while deactivate value is still blank`. For example, in your initial situation, the columns "B" and "C" are empty? If it's so, do you want to make user select "deactivate" and "activate" in order?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike Thank you for your assistance, and sorry for the confusion. That is correct, when both Column B or C are empty then they should be prompted for an alert or message box. And activate should always come first before they can choose deactivate.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `when both Column B or C are empty then they should be prompted for an alert or message box.`, in this case, when the columns "B" and "C" are empty at the initial situation and the user opens your HTML, you want to show an alert soon. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Hey sorry, just the column C will do. If there's an entry for Activate already and user selected activate again then that's where the alert should prompt. (Enactment still active, please select deactivate if you wish to terminate the lever)

Comment: And I have another request if I may. I really appreciate your help. Is it possible to display the running duration as well in the form if it's still ongoing or hasn't been deactivated.

Comment: Please share a sample/copy of your spreadsheet with the script so we can easily replicate what you have. Remove sensitive data if any.

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets/images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) as the only source of data. Make sure to add input and expected output as plain text table to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are easier to copy/paste as well. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: Hey guys. Appreciate your responses. I guess the final output that I want is add time input entry to column B when selected dropdown is Activate, while if user choose Deactivate it should be added to column C. Thank you guys

Comment: @coders_key thanks for clarifying your desired output. However, you are more likely to get an answer by sharing a copy/sample spreadsheet so people can easily replicate what you have instead of building from the scratch to provide you a tested solution.

Comment: @Logan Sorry for the delay. Here's the mock copy of the sheets. Thank you for your help in advance. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FPwpA0OLhSEHn9166T7pdepbFsCkc13eW8xdQHnnVf8/edit#gid=4695799

Comment: Currently, data is being saved in Feedback sheet, but what I want to achieve is the format that I have in Sheet2.

Comment: @Tanaike Apologies for the confusion. Kindly see above copy of the sheets. Appreciate your help. I also updated the desired output above.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Is it possible to display the running duration as well in the form if it's still ongoing or hasn't been deactivated.` in your comment, is this your 4th request? And, in your situation, if user "A" and user "B" access your Web Apps, simultaneously, what result do you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes Sir, if it's possible so that user can see in the form if it's still active. And regarding -  if user "A" and user "B" access your Web Apps, simultaneously, what result do you want to achieve? - Form is only being access by one user at a time.

Comment: @Tanaike I've updated my original question to reflect the 4th requests. Thank you.

Comment: @Tanaike No worries at all. I have made another inquiry to clarify my question. Apologies if my questions are confusing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74830093/google-web-app-append-data-based-on-user-data-selection

Comment: Thank you for replying. I will check it. When I have a question, I will ask it.